# Vue js array dynamic loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im having two arrays : `days:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `wdays:[2,3,6]`

I want to loop through both the array and the output must be as follows :

- 0 : not present
- 1 : not present
- 2 : present
- 3 : present
- 4 : not present etc...

and the code must be in `vue.js`

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information here to provide a definitive answer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: add some codes and example

Comment: What do you mean by *the code must be in vue.js* ? It's all about the logic which should be in JavaScript.

Comment: Its like im getting the working days from the backend node as an array of object. If one day is working they will be sending the corresponding number (eg;if sunday working the number will be 0..).So i want to loop through the array and print the days in order as available or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      days:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
      wdays:[2,3,6]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.days.map(d => {
        return this.wdays.includes(d) ? {[d]: 'present'} : {[d]: 'not present'}
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ Object.keys(item)[0]  }}: {{ Object.values(item)[0] }}
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*the code must be in vue.js* - I think it should me more of logic to check the values of one array into an another array.

You can simply achieve that by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method with the help of [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

```js
const days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

const wdays = [2,3,6];

const res = days.map(item => {
    return !wdays.includes(item) ? 'Not present' : 'Present'
});

console.log(res);
```